# How exactly is the depth slope for glPolygonOffset computed?

Tags: opengl

In

```
glPolygonOffset(factor, units)
```

factor is multiplied with the (possibly approximated) depth slope *m*, which is a derivative in screen space if i understand this correctly.

Is *m* is calculated per polygon (lets stick to triangles) and then used in the depth-offset operation for every depth-buffer fragment belonging to that polygon **or** is it computed per fragment somehow ?

(Or is there a third way?)

Comment: For polygons, the slope of the entire thing is known before rasterization (it is constant because polygons in GL are always planar). There's no reason to evaluate this per-fragment, once is enough. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Do you want to do this in a fragment shader?

Comment: @Andon Thanks. I am just trying to understand what parts of my rendered geometry are most susceptible for a wrong visibility computation in the visibility computation algorithm i have implemented when decreasing depthbuffer resolution. As this is GPGPU, exactness is key for me. The answer you gave was what i thought in the first place. However i got suspicios, because depth slope is officially allowed to be computed as max(|dz/dx|, |dz/dy|), which might be done similar to dFdx in GLSL (although in that case i don't know what happens if there is no valid neighbor fragment).

Comment: Oh, I'd almost be more concerned with the second parameter. That's an implementation-dependent offset (`unit` is multiplied by the smallest value that is distinguishable during rasterization _and_ when written to the depth buffer - _epsilon_ in other words). To figure out the value that `unit` is multiplied by will take a little bit of work on your part, you cannot query it from GL.

Comment: That is no problem for me, i am rendering a pushed-back filled polygon mesh into the depthbuffer in the first pass and then query points in a shader without offsets to ensure points on the front surface turn out as visible. Fortunately i only need to know what parts might be critical, now that i know i do not need to compensate. If i had to i would indeed prefer implementing a linearized db myself instead of fiddeling with the unknown unit ;)